# Is there any way to get pure JSON response with AFNetworking Obj-C?

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking, codable

I already have an architecture setup with AFNetworking in my iOS app that is written in Obj-C. It returns the response as a Dictionary but I would like to play around with a pure JSON response to try Codable in Swift 4. 
Is that possible? Or what would be my options here?

Comment: Are you using an instance of `AFJSONResponseSerializer` as the `AFHTTPSessionManager` response serializer?

Comment: Yes, I am using the default one.

Comment: Can you show, How your dictionary output is? & how JSON you need ?

Comment: If you use `AFHTTPSessionManager` instead of `AFJSONResponseSerializer`, then the response should be returned as `NSData` (if my memory serves me well). Then, you can use `NSJSONSerialization` on it yourself, of your Codable.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution recreate a JSON :

```
var dataJson = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: responseObject, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
var objCodable = try! JSONDecoder().decode(ObjCodable.self, from: dataJson)
```